# error - accept() failed: Bad file descriptor

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have to implement two processes that have to interact through TCP, basically a file transfer between a server and a client (school homework). Everything work for the first file transmission but when the client ends its job the server crashes because of `error - accept() failed: Bad file descriptor`.

**server_main.c**

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char cwd[100];

    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) {
       printf("App[starting]: " ANSI_COLOR_CYAN "%s" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n", cwd);
    } else {
       printf("App[quitting]: " ANSI_COLOR_RED "UNABLE TO LOCATE WDIR" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
       return 1;
    }

    // procedo solo se vengono passati esattamente due parametri allo script
    // 1. il nome dello script (default)
    // 2. la porta
    if (argc == 2) {
        int passiveSocket = startTcpServer(argv[1]);
        runIterativeTcpInstance(passiveSocket);
        close(passiveSocket);
        return 0;
    }

    // se arrivo qui ho app crash
    printf("App[quitting]: " ANSI_COLOR_RED "USAGE: <PORT>" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");

    return 1;
}
```

**gj_server.c**

```
int startTcpServer(const char* port) {

    uint16_t i_port;
    int sockfd;

    sockfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    parsePort(port, &i_port);
    bindToAny(sockfd, i_port);
    Listen(sockfd, 516);
    printf("Server[listening]: " ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "PORT = %d, BACKLOG = 516" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n", (int) i_port);

    return sockfd;
}

void runIterativeTcpInstance(int passiveSock) {

    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
    socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while(1) {
        printf("Server[accepting]: " ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW "WAITING FOR A CONNECTION..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
        int connSock = Accept(passiveSock , (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &addr_len);
        doTcpJob(connSock);
        close(connSock);
    }

}

void doTcpJob(int connSock) {
    //TODO: uscire in caso di errore di una delle due fasi
    printf("Server[connection]:" ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "STARTED A NEW ON CONNECTION (PID=%d)" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n", getpid());
    char request[256];
    initStr(request, 256);
    if(doTcpReceive(connSock, request) == 0)
        doTcpSend(connSock, request);
    else {
        printf("Server[error]: " ANSI_COLOR_RED "INVALID REQUEST FROM CLIENT: %s" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n", request);
        char err_buff[7] = "-ERR\r\n";
        send(connSock, err_buff, 6, 0);
        //close(connSock);
    }
```

//close(connSock);
    }

```
int doTcpReceive(int connSock, char *request) {

    struct timeval tval;
    fd_set cset;
    FD_ZERO(&cset);
    FD_SET(connSock, &cset);
    tval.tv_sec = 15;
    tval.tv_usec = 0;
    if(Select(FD_SETSIZE, &cset, NULL, NULL, &tval) == 1) {
        // TODO: INSERIRE LOGICA RECEIVE QUI
        ssize_t read = 0;
        while (reqCompleted(request) == -1 ) {
         ssize_t received = Recv(connSock, request, 256, 0); 
         read += received;
        }
        printf("Server[receive]: " ANSI_COLOR_CYAN "RECEIVED %s" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n", request);
        return checkRequest(request);
    }
    // esco per timeout
    //close(connSock);
    return -1;
}

void doTcpSend(int connSock, char *request) {
    // TODO: INSERIRE LOGICA SEND QUI

    // 1. send ok message
    char ok_msg[6] = "+OK\r\n";
    send(connSock, ok_msg, 5, 0);

    // 2. send file size
    FILE *fp = fopen(request, "rb+");

    // qui il file dovrebbe esistere, ma potrebbe essere inacessibile o
    // l'apertura potrebbe fallire
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("SERVER[READING]" ANSI_COLOR_RED "CANNOT OPEN FILE %s " ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n", request);
        char err_buff[7] = "-ERR\r\n";
        send(connSock, err_buff, 6, 0);
        //close(connSock);
        return;
    }

    struct stat stat_buf;

    if (fstat(fileno(fp), &stat_buf) == 0) {

        long f_size = stat_buf.st_size;
        long f_time = stat_buf.st_mtime;
        uint32_t net_f_size = htonl(f_size);
        send(connSock, &net_f_size, 4, 0);

        // 3. send file content
        ssize_t sent = 0;
        printf("fsize: %d", (int)f_size);
        while (sent < f_size) {
            sent += sendfile(connSock, fileno(fp), NULL, f_size);
            showProgress((int)sent, (int)f_size, "Server[sending]: ");
        }

        fclose(fp);

        // 4. send file timestamp
        uint32_t net_f_time = htonl(f_time);
        send(connSock, &net_f_time, 4, 0); 
        //close(connSock);

    } else {
        char err_buff[7] = "-ERR\r\n";
        send(connSock, err_buff, 6, 0);
        //close(connSock);
        return;
    }


}

int reqCompleted(char *request) {
    int len = strlen(request);
    return len > 6 && request[len - 2] == '\r' && request[len - 1] == '\n' ? 0 : -1;
}

int checkRequest(char *request) {
    int len = strlen(request);
    if (len > 6 && request[0] == 'G' && request[1] == 'E' && request[2] == 'T'
        && request[3] == ' ' && request[len - 2] == '\r' && request[len - 1] == '\n') {
            memcpy(request, request + 4, (len - 6)); // estraggo il nome del file dalla richiesta
            request[len - 6] = '\0';
            return access(request, F_OK); // verifico che il file esista nella cartella di lavoro
        }
    return -1;
}
```

the parameter called `passiveSock` causes the problem, at the second iteration of the while loop, I'm quite new in C and I think it's relative to life cycle of a variable. I've already tried to print `passiveSock` before the accept call and gives me an error. This is the valgrind output:

```sh
==1== Syscall param accept(s) contains uninitialised byte(s)
==1==    at 0x4F21990: __accept_nocancel (syscall-template.S:84)
==1==    by 0x10A7D4: Accept (sockwrap.c:97)
==1==    by 0x109AA5: runIterativeTcpInstance (gj_server.c:28)
==1== 
((null)) error - accept() failed: Bad file descriptor
==1== 
==1== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,576 bytes allocated
==1== 
==1== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1== 
==1== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==1== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**EDIT sockwrap.c Accept definition**

```
int Accept (int listen_sockfd, SA *cliaddr, socklen_t *addrlenp)
{
    int n;
again:
    if ( (n = accept(listen_sockfd, cliaddr, addrlenp)) < 0)
    {
        if (INTERRUPTED_BY_SIGNAL ||
            errno == EPROTO || errno == ECONNABORTED ||
            errno == EMFILE || errno == ENFILE ||
            errno == ENOBUFS || errno == ENOMEM         
            )
            goto again;
        else
            err_sys ("(%s) error - accept() failed", prog_name);
    }
    return n;
}
```

**initStr and showProgress**

```
void initStr(char* string, int length) {
    memset(string, '\0', length);
    string[length] = '\0';
}

void showProgress(int done, int tot, char * progMsg) {
    int progress = ((double) done / (double) tot) * 100;
    printf("\r%s " ANSI_COLOR_CYAN "%d bytes (%d%%)" ANSI_COLOR_RESET, progMsg, done, progress);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: The lifetime of `passiveSock` is the entire time that `runIterativeTcpInstance` is running. I don't see anything that changes it, and it isn't closed until the function returns (which it never does). I don't see how this could be happening unless there's a buffer overrun that writes to it.

Comment: Can you show the `Accept` wrapper function?

Comment: @Barmar I agree with that but at the second cycle it gives this error due that variable :(

Comment: @kaylum yeah off course, these functions are taken from the Steven books (professor provide us these functions) I will edit my post with the definition of the wrapper

Comment: So something we can't see in the code you posted must be overwriting it due to a buffer overrun.

Comment: @Barmar I'll show the rest of the code :)

Comment: Use a debugger, and tell it to watch the `passiveSock` variable for modifications.

Comment: Maybe handle EAGAIN?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz doTcpJob close connection on error only, I've removed it because it's not needed but this not solve the issue

Comment: Are you sure passiveSock is not closed anywhere else in your code before next time calling accept ()? Are you forking a child anywhere else in your main code, and closing passiveSock there? Can you share value of passiveSock before each call to accept.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried to debug it using gdb, but we have to use a docker container for the process so it's not very simple for me (I have many skills in C debuggin :D ) but in the first iteration passiveSock is equals to 3 and in the second cycle (gdb) print passiveSock
No symbol "passiveSock" in current context. I don't know if I missed something debugging

Comment: @GJCode Add logging temporarily to make it easier to understand exactly what your code is doing. If you wrap `close` into a `Close` function, you can then just add logging to your wrappers.

Comment: @GJCode I can't see how you could get that error. If you're in the `runIterativeTcpInstance` function, the `passiveSock` variable should be in scope.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've edited the question, I've removed every close(connSock) from the code (I hope I didin't missed someone on edit) eccept the one after the doTcpJob() that now is the only close call. The issue still the same, at the first iteration passiveSock is equals to 3 at the second iteration passiveSock is not initalized bytes

Comment: if the function getpid() do not make a fork I do not change context, but I don't know where is the error, this is why I've posted my issue here, but I don't know why the downvote to my question

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've posted the whole server code, the Accept function is taken from a library. I've replied to all the comments at my best, and I think I've explained my problem in the right way (unless for my broken english) so I don't know why the downvote

Comment: @GJCode The first function I went to check was `initStr`, and we don't have the code for it. :( The second was `showProgress`, and ...  ditto.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz just added these two functions :)

Comment: I suspect the downvote was because you didn't confirm that you could replicate the bug with just the code given which made the question unanswerable. If you choose not to give us any code, you must 100% confirm that you can replicate the problem without that code.

Comment: Besides, `Listen(sockfd, 516);` , the value `516` is mildly insane. Don't do this until you know what at acually does. (anyway, the kernel will clip this to a sane value, like 128. Normally, a smaller number (below 10) is sufficient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the bug was in the first function I wanted to check. Look closely:

```
    void initStr(char* string, int length) {
        memset(string, '\0', length);
        string[length] = '\0'; // <-- BOOM!
    }
```

But:

```
    char request[256];
    initStr(request, 256);
```

So `request` is an array with 256 entries. But `initStr` writes into the 257th entry, which does not exist.

You should get rid of this function and never use anything even remotely like it. Filling an entire buffer with zeroes serves no purpose. Instead, properly track the length of the data in the buffer and stop calling `strlen` all the time. There are other bugs in your code because of this, much more subtle ones.

For example, you try to read 256 bytes from the connection. This could fill your entire buffer, replacing all the zero bytes. You then pass the buffer to `strlen` -- but there is no guarantee there is a zero byte anywhere in the buffer.

Data received over a network connection is *not* a string. It's raw data with a known length that is returned from the `read` or `recv` function. Don't pretend it is a string. It's a bad habit that will bite you again and again and again.

Comment: The second line of the function is unnecessary anyway, as indeed is the whole function. You don't need to initialize buffers you're about to read into. `recv()` gives the length received.

Comment: @user207421 He does because he passes the buffer to `strlen`. But I updated my answer to explain why that's bad, bad, bad!

Comment: as I said I'm new in C and I'm tryng to understand how things work ( I mean I think in one week I cannot understand everything) I know that this error is not related to C, but sometimes is not easy to see what is obvious, I've missed the wrong array position. I've appreciated all your comments and I will go deeper with C language.

Comment: @GJCode You might want to spend some time writing code that's just a little bit simpler and then post it to a [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for advice. This will help you clean up a lot of little things about your code that will help prevent you from acquiring bad habits and get you some good ones.